# How do I include a Perl module that's in a different directory?

Tags: perl, module

How do I include a Perl module that's in a different directory?  It needs to be a relative path from the module that's including it.

I've tried

```
push ( @INC,"directory_path/more_path");
```

also

```
push ( @INC,"directory_path\\more_path");
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

EDIT: Putting the right solution first, originally from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185114/how-do-i-use-a-perl-module-in-a-directory-not-in-inc).  It's the only one that searches relative to the **module** directory:

```
use FindBin;                 # locate this script
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/..";  # use the parent directory
use yourlib;
```

There's many other ways that search for libraries relative to the **current** directory.  You can invoke perl with the -I argument, passing the directory of the other module:

```
perl -I.. yourscript.pl
```

You can include a line near the top of your perl script:

```
use lib '..';
```

You can modify the environment variable PERL5LIB before you run the script:

```
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:..
```

The push(@INC) strategy can also work, but it has to be wrapped in BEGIN{} to make sure that the push is run before the module search:

```
BEGIN {push @INC, '..'}
use yourlib;
```

Comment: After many attempts the code that finally worked was from the question that Andomar linked to:

use FindBin;                 # locate this scriptuse lib "$FindBin::Bin/..";  # use the parent directory
use EPMS;

Thank you for all of your help everyone!

Comment: Cheers, looks like everyone read "current directory" where you wrote "module's directory".

Comment: Came across this after reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/90721/2668831 which claims the FindBin method isn't robust for some forms of modular Perl organisation (someone else may be able to clarify)

Answer (score 15):

Most likely the reason your push did not work is order of execution.

`use` is a compile time directive.  You `push` is done at execution time:

```
push ( @INC,"directory_path/more_path");
use Foo.pm;  # In directory path/more_path
```

You can use a BEGIN block to get around this problem:

```
BEGIN {
    push ( @INC,"directory_path/more_path");
}
use Foo.pm;  # In directory path/more_path
```

IMO, it's clearest, and therefore best to `use lib`:

```
use lib "directory_path/more_path";
use Foo.pm;  # In directory path/more_path
```

See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) for information about BEGIN and other special blocks and when they execute.

**Edit**

For loading code relative to your script/library, I strongly endorse [File::FindLib](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::FindLib)

You can say `use File::FindLib 'my/test/libs';` to look for a library directory anywhere above your script in the path.

Say your work is structured like this:

```
   /home/me/projects/
    |- shared/
    |   |- bin/
    |   `- lib/
    `- ossum-thing/
       `- scripts 
           |- bin/
           `- lib/
```

Inside a script in `ossum-thing/scripts/bin`:

```
use File::FindLib 'lib/';
use File::FindLib 'shared/lib/';
```

Will find your library directories and add them to your `@INC`.

It's also useful to create a module that contains all the environment set-up needed to run your suite of tools and just load it in all the executables in your project.

```
use File::FindLib 'lib/MyEnvironment.pm'
```

Answer (score 10):

'use lib' can also take a single string value...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '<relative-path>';
use <your lib>;
```

Comment: What is the relative path relative to?

Answer (score 7):

From [perlfaq8:](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_add_the_dir)

---

**How do I add the directory my program lives in to the module/library search path?**

(contributed by brian d foy)

If you know the directory already, you can add it to @INC as you would for any other directory. You might use lib if you know the directory at compile time:

```
use lib $directory;
```

The trick in this task is to find the directory. Before your script does anything else (such as a chdir), you can get the current working directory with the Cwd module, which comes with Perl:

```
BEGIN {
    use Cwd;
    our $directory = cwd;
    }

use lib $directory;
```

You can do a similar thing with the value of $0, which holds the script name. That might hold a relative path, but rel2abs can turn it into an absolute path. Once you have the

```
BEGIN {
    use File::Spec::Functions qw(rel2abs);
    use File::Basename qw(dirname);

    my $path   = rel2abs( $0 );
    our $directory = dirname( $path );
    }

use lib $directory;
```

The FindBin module, which comes with Perl, might work. It finds the directory of the currently running script and puts it in $Bin, which you can then use to construct the right library path:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
```

Comment: Your second suggestion (using `cwd` inside a `BEGIN` block) does not seem to work. All I get is the following error: `Variable "$directory" is not imported at ./thingy line 16. //
Global symbol "$directory" requires explicit package name at ./thingy line 16. //
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at ./thingy line 16.`

Comment: You'd have to show me your code. It sounds like you might have quoted $directory in the import list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned it before, but [FindBin::libs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin%3A%3Alibs) will always find your libs as it searches in all reasonable places relative to the location of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use FindBin::libs;
use <your lib>;
```

Comment: And I'm surprised that 7 years on your answer didn't get a single upvote. Have one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how it can be done in eclipse. My dev system - Windows 64bit, Eclipse Luna, Perlipse plugin for eclipse, Strawberry pearl installer. I use perl.exe as my interpreter.

Eclipse > create new perl project > right click project > build path > configure build path > libraries tab > add external source folder > go to the folder where all your perl modules are installed > ok > ok. Done !