# Redmine - Git push fails [remote rejected] hook declined

Tags: git, redmine, githooks, gitolite

I am having problem with pushing to my server which hosts redmine and repositories. I do have gitolite redmine plugin for redmine & latest gitolite v3.5.x. When i clone repository i.e.

```
git clone git@<ip address>:repositories/test-project-redmine.git 
// btw: i do get asked for password even though i have send my public key to redmine ?
```

this repository is cloned without a problem. When i create a simple readme.txt file and then i try to push this back to the repository i get the following

[image]

any one what can cause this issue ? Thanks :)

**Update:**

I have run `find / -path '*Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm' -print 2>/dev/null` and yes the files do exist. Also i have checked the file permissions for user `'git'` who runs the repositories and he has all required permissions. Picture attached.

[image]

however search did not return anything regarding perl

I have found [THIS](https://github.com/jbox-web/redmine_git_hosting/wiki/Troubleshooting#hook-errors-while-pushing-over-https) on the github - official plugin page - theoretical solution to the problem. I have done as suggested with inserting this:

```
__DATA__
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN {
  exit 0 if exists $ENV{GL_BYPASS_UPDATE_HOOK};
}

use strict;
use warnings;
...
```

into the following files:

```
/<git user home dir>/bin/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm
/<git user home dir>/gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm
/<git user home dir>/.gitolite/hooks/common/update
```

however still no success... ?

Comment: This is an incorrect installation of [git `pre-recieve` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the remote side. The hook is written in perl and some perl modules are missing

Comment: @user3159253 i have all perl modules on server, so it can not be missing something

Comment: Well, it says clearly about it. I would suggest to check existance of Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm (use `find / -path '*Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm' -print 2>/dev/null`) then if the file actually exists, check if it resides in directories, in which `perl` searches for modules (copy `@INC` from the message), and finally check that the module file permissions are suitable for the account which runs th repository.

Comment: @user3159253 i have checked and the file exists + correct permisions are set for user who runs the repository. search returned 0 regarding perl. And i do not quite get what should i copy where - Question edited

Comment: Well, you may check if the hook isn't executed in a chrooted or somehow else restricted environment. Or, better, you may copy this and other required modules right into the hook directory, preserving the structure (that is, `<hookdir>/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm`). This is of course an ugly solution, but may be it helps

Comment: @user3159253 could you kindly tell me how do i add the path to '@INC' i tried to google where is the file that contains the list but i can not find it

Answer (score 0):

Well, StackOverflow suggests [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841785/how-do-i-include-a-perl-module-thats-in-a-different-directory):

```
use lib '/path/you/want/to/add';
```

right in the beginning of the script, before other `use` and `require` directives. But remember! there's literally a decennary since I did some perl last time, so you'd better check twice :)

Comment: Cool the question is in which file do i put the directory to the .pm module ?

Comment: Hm, likely there should be .git/hooks/pre-receive in your repository

Comment: unfortunately there isn't

Comment: Ok so it seems like the reason why i get this error is because i cloned the repository ommiting gitolite - and when i try to push back it throws this error. according to specifications i should use git@<ip>:<repo name> but this returns back 'fatal: repo does not appear to be a git repository, 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository..'... Please make sure you have the correct access rights..