# In Perl, can't locate packgeName.pm in @INC error

Tags: perl, module, package

This is a module `math.pm` with 2 basic functions add and multiply:

```
package Math;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(add multiply); 

sub add {
my ($x, $y) = @_;
return $x + $y;
}

sub multiply {
my ($x, $y) = @_;
return $x * $y;
}

1;
```

This is script `script.pl` that call the add function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math qw(add);
print add(19, 23);
```

It gives an error:

> can't locate math.pm in @INC  <@INC contain: C:/perl/site/lib C:/perl/lib .> at C:\programs\script.pl line 5.
>       BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\programs\script.pl line 5.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: hey @serenesat prob is in  this code is not working and giving such kind of error

Comment: For me its working fine. If you put both program on same path. It should work.

Comment: don't knw what was wrong when m running this program

Comment: In the error message it says `math.pm` and your code shows `package Math;` (in file called `Math.pm`) - you have to use the correct capitalization. Check the file name of your module and your script `use math;` will cause the error message you have shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include a Perl module that's in a different directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841785/how-do-i-include-a-perl-module-thats-in-a-different-directory)

Comment: FYI https://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse

Answer (score 11):

[use lib](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

> Adding a use lib statement to the script will add the directory to @INC for that specific script. Regardless who and in what environment runs it.
>
> You just have to make sure to have the use lib statement before trying to load the module:

```
use lib '/path/to/module';
use Math qw(add);
```

For more details to set @INC look at this:

[How do I include a Perl module that's in a different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841812/4248931)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `script.pl` before `use Math ...;`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

If `script.pl` and `math.pm` aren't in the same directory, adjust accordingly.

Also, you might have problems if the file is named `math.pm` and you use `use Math;` and `package Math;`. It would be best to rename the file so the spelling is consistent.

```
ren math.pm Math.pm
```