# Get the current working directory path in Perl

Tags: perl

I am getting the perl script location using `$FindBin::RealBin`. Now I have a problem using this.
I am calling a Perl script from one Perl script.
In the caller script, `$FindBin::RealBin` is working fine, but in the called Perl script, it is not giving the location. 
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Does this work http://perl.active-venture.com/lib/Cwd.html ?

Comment: `$FindBin` is used to find the directory where the Perl script is located.  That is different from the current working directory of the Perl process.  Which are you really looking for?

Comment: i want to get the perl script locations only.. how do i get it in the called perl script.. when i use $FindBin::RealBin it is empty. anyother way to get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the full path to a Perl script that is executing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84932/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-to-a-perl-script-that-is-executing)

Answer (score 5):

This is what I always use:

```
my ($vol,$script_path, $prog) = File::Spec->splitpath(File::Spec->rel2abs( __FILE__ ));
```

Check if it works in your case. It should work if you call your inner script as a shell call. I don't know if it would work if you call it with `do`.

Some readings about this:

see [How do I get the full path to a Perl script that is executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84932/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-to-a-perl-script-that-is-executing)

FindBin::Bin is broken http://use.perl.org/~Aristotle/journal/33995 (or the google cache http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y-5OZsxdTT8J:use.perl.org/~Aristotle/journal/33995)

File::Basename http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html is more problematic

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

As you did not provide a full code sample, this is more a guess. 
According to the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html), you need to call

```
FindBin::again();
```

as this is a known limitation of FindBin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use `realpath` from [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) .

```
$ cat ./mycode
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
print "called as '$0'\n";
print "lives  in '", Cwd::realpath($0), "'\n";

$ ./mycode
called as './mycode'
lives  in '/Users/jrf/Sandbox/mycode'
```